# How to go through JSON data to create a list, even the children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-lists

I have a JSON object that I need to create a list out of.

I would be able to do it fine but each object can have children. It looks something like this :

```
{
    "Boys" : 
    [
        {
            "name" : "Fred",
            "age" : "65",
            "children" : [{
                    "name" : "dave",
                    "age" : "24",
                    "children" : []
                }, {
                    "name" : "cliff",
                    "age" : "32",
                    "children" : []
                }
            ]
        },  
        {
            "name" : "jon",
            "age" : "46",
            "children" : [{
                    "name" : "jess",
                    "age" : "26",
                    "children" : []
                }, {
                    "name" : "gloria",
                    "age" : "19",
                    "children" : []
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Girls" : 
    [
        {
            "name" : "Jane",
            "age" : "65",
            "children" : [{
                    "name" : "dave",
                    "age" : "24",
                    "children" : []
                }, {
                    "name" : "grace",
                    "age" : "32",
                    "children" : []
                }
            ]
        },  
        {
            "name" : "ariana",
            "age" : "46",
            "children" : [{
                    "name" : "jessy",
                    "age" : "28",
                    "children" : []
                }, {
                    "name" : "niki",
                    "age" : "19",
                    "children" : []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd be able to go through it fine in a for-loop but I'm unsure how to go through the children too.

Basically I want to go through each element and create a list item with the text being the name of the object I am currently at.

So for the JSON above it would be something like :

```
-Boys
   -Fred
      -Dave
      -Cliff
   -Jon
      -Jess
      -Gloria
-Girls
   -Jane
      -Dave
      -Grace
   -Ariana
      -Jessy
      -Niki
```

After I create this list I will be using JSTree to format it, any help is appreciated :)

Comment: So, you want to build a literal tree of `ul` / `li` elements?

Comment: Why aren't you passing the data directly to jsTree? Seems pointless to render it in dom from json, then have jStree parse dom to recreate the same data

Comment: i didnt know you could do that. I thought you have to pass it the list container ?

Comment: @thisOneGuy: Yea, [you can do that.](https://www.jstree.com/docs/json/)

Comment: @Cerbrus just looked it up, the JSON has to be in a certain format, I think creating the list elements from my current JSON data would be easier that  changing my JSON data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a recursive function, a function that calls itself until something happens. In your case, you need a function that goes through a list of people. For each person, it'd paint the name, then would check if that person has children. If it does, then calls the function again, passing it the list of children.

Something like this:

```js
var renderList = function(list){
    var $list = $('<ul>');

    $.each(list, function(i, element){
        var $child = $('<li>'+element.name+'</li>');
        if (element.children.length > 0) {
            $child.append(renderList(element.children));
        }
        $list.append($child);
    });

    return $list;
};    

$('#boys').append(renderList(data.Boys)); // Start list of boys
$('#girls').append(renderList(data.Girls)); // Start list of girls
```

Working example here http://jsfiddle.net/zbm778ag/

Comment: looks perfect, just what I need. Ill try implement it with my work now and let you know if it works :)

Comment: few tweeks needed for mine as the data is slightly different to what I showed. But it works great, thank you